# How to convert Zeplin Single screen into android layout file

Tags: android, android-layout, zeplin

I want to convert zeplin single screen to android layout file, which I can directly import/copy into android studio and use it into my android project.

Ex: In zeplin screen I have 2 text view and one button from this zeplin screen android layout should generate with button, text and styles property.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.